# Git or rsync to move code that might not compile

Tags: git, rsync

I am implementing CUDA GPU algorithms on my computer but I don't have a CUDA GPU. So I need to move my files from my computer to a distant one to compile them. Both local and distant directories have a git repository.

But I feel uncomfortable commiting and pushing a code that might not compile. That's why I am currently using `rsync` to synchronize the directories, and `git` only when my code compiles and work.

Is there a way to use only git?

(I would not be surprised if that question was a duplicate, but I couldn't find any similar case.)

Answer (score 0):

how about : https://github.com/simonthum/git-sync

By default, commit is done using:

```
git add -u ; git commit -m "changes from $(uname -n) on $(date)"
```

Or if you enable syncNewFiles:

```
git add -A ; git commit -m \"changes from $(uname -n) on $(date)\";"
```